# How to calculate torsion elements of non-abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was showing that the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2$ is an infinite group. To do that I used the homomorphism given by $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2$ sending 1 to $ab$.

I showed that $\varphi(m)$ is never zero for non zero $m$. Since in that case $a$,$b$ would lie in the same conjugacy class and taking the quotient by the normal subgroup generated by $<a>$ i would have $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2/<a> \cong 0$ and thats absurd.

However, this could be much easier if we knew the torsion elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2$. I'm aware of some basic notions of $Tor$ functors but I think this only works in the abelian case.

What are the ways of finding torsion elements with non-abelian groups?

Comment: It is hard to answer such a general question, but there is a result about free products that any torsion element of a group $G=A*B$ is conjugate in $G$ to an element of $A$ or of $B$. So the torsion elements of $G$ are essentially determined b y those of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: For free products, say $A * B$, (and more generally free products with amalgamation) we know that every element of finite order in $A * B$ is conjugated to an element (of nevessary finite order) in the factors, i.e. $A$ or $B$.